# An exception occurred processing JSP page [/views/index.jsp]

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have an error in spring mvc.

The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page [/views/index.jsp] at line [21]
18: <div class="row section-row">
19:     <div class="col-xs-12 section-col">
20: 
21:         <h:dataTable value="#{homeController.allNews}" var="news">
22: 
23:             <h:column>
24:                 <f:facet name="header">Title</f:facet>

Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:584)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:481)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:894)
org.apache.jsp.views.home_jsp._jspService(home_jsp.java:121)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:91)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

My Home Controller Code :

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class HomeController {


news_simple news = new news_simple();

ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ProjectConfig.class);

NewsService service = context.getBean(NewsService.class);


public List<news_simple> getAllNews() {
    List<news_simple> x = service.GetAll();
    return x;
}

public news_simple getNews() {
    return news;
}
public void setBook(news_simple news) {
    this.news = news;
}
}
```

in my home.jsp code :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" %>
<div class="row section-row">
<div class="col-xs-12 section-col">

    <h:dataTable value="#{homeController.allNews}" var="news">

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Title</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{news.title}"></h:outputText>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Content</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{news.content}"></h:outputText>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Date</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{news.date}"></h:outputText>
        </h:column>

    </h:dataTable>

</div>
```

In Home Controller I have an object with name news, and this object has setter and getter.

in addition, getAllNews worked when i call it with My test controller. and ApplicationContext and NewsService has been return data successfully.

Comment: I have had never using JSF, the first thing that caught my eye it is the anatation ManagedBean. By default created bean with class name, try to add name, in your case @ManagedBean(name="allNews"), maybe it helps

Comment: @ManagedBean(name="allNews") Had no effect. :(

Comment: show me your import statement in your controller class

Comment: it should be like this `import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;`

Comment: later, add this line `@ManagedBean(name = "homeController")`

Comment: its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why `jsf` not worked. but I changed my code to `jsp` and used jsp files instead of jsf.

Home Controller :

```
@Controller
@Scope(value = "request")
public class HomeController {

 @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String Home(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws 
 Exception {
    List<NewsDoc> list = getTopNewsList();
    request.setAttribute("list", list);
    return "Home";
}
```

and in top of Home.jsp :

```
<% List<NewsDoc> newsList = (List<NewsDoc>) request.getAttribute("list");
```

and where I want to see result :

```
<% for (NewsDoc news : newsList) { %>
    <h2><%=news.getTitle()%></h2>
    <p>
        <%=news.getAbout()%>
    </p>
<% } %>
```